# Powershell Wait-process until installation complete

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-11, silent-installer

```
$computers = Read-host "Enter Computer Name"

$computers | where{test-connection $_ -quiet -count 1} | ForEach-Object {

    copy-item C:\SoftwareAndDrivers\IE11 -recurse "\\$_\c$\temp" 

    $newProc=([WMICLASS]"\\$_\root\cimv2:win32_Process").Create("C:\TEMP\IE11\IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe /quiet /norestart /update-no")

    If ($newProc.ReturnValue -eq 0) { Write-Host $_ $newProc.ProcessId } else { write-host $_ Process create failed with $newProc.ReturnValue }

    Wait-Process -Id $newProc.ProcessId

    Write-Host "Installed Successfully" -ForegroundColor Green

}
```

I want the script to pause until IE11 is installed and then continue and show "Installed Successfully". I can't get it to pause though. I get

> Wait-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier xxxx

Comment: From technet: Wait-Process works only on processes running on the local computer.

Comment: Get-Process -ComputerName $computers | Sort-Object id -Descending


do {(Write-Host "Waiting..."),(Start-Sleep -Seconds 5)}
until ((Get-WMIobject -Class Win32_process -Filter "Name='IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe'" -ComputerName $computers | 
where {$_.Name -eq "IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe"}).ProcessID -eq $null)

Write-Host "Installed Successfully" -ForegroundColor Green